# What is smart casual dress code?

Tags: dress-code

I have been called to attend an interview in a government parastatal and they told me to be in "smart casual". What kind of wear is smart casual ?

Comment: Have you looked at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_casual)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is appropriate dress for a "business casual" interview?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/what-is-appropriate-dress-for-a-business-casual-interview)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jeans in an interview](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20419/jeans-in-an-interview)

Comment: LMGTFY (because I was interested): government parastatal: government-owned corporation or similar. In the US: Fannie Mae is an example.

Comment: For men, I define it as formal dress minus-a-tie.

Comment: @strazzere  upvote for the link to illustration pics

Comment: It means that a suit and tie are not necessary. As the others have noted a dress shirt is fine. I will add that there is a bit more latitude in what you can get away with: stronger colors and patterns are OK. You can probably get away with a high quality crew-neck sweater. In general, you can "bend the rules" somewhat if your taste is impeccable and you look good (highly subjective, but it works).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Smart casual" is a slight step up (typically) from business casual. It's not as formal as proper business attire but it's close. I'd recommend pressed slacks, an oxford style or similar button down long-sleeve shirt and a proper coat/jacket to go with it. You won't need a tie, an unbuttoned collar should be good enough. In some environments a stylish jean might be acceptable, but I wouldn't recommend it for an interview.